# Restlet send "get" request to server and process response

Tags: java, https, restlet, apache-commons-httpclient

I would like to send a `get` request to a remote server using `Restlet` and receive the response (as `Json`).

Here is my starting point, please feel free to complete:

```
ClientResource cr = new ClientResource("https://"+url);

JsonRepresentation r = (JsonRepresentation) cr.get();

r.getJsonObject().get("MY_VALUE");
```

**Restlet** version 2.1.7

**Json**: `{"title":"General Terms & Conditions","version":"20022014_001"}`

Comment: It's difficult like that to guess ;-) Could you me a exception stacktrace? Thanks!

Comment: it was hang-up.
It falls on `ClassCastException`.
So obviously casting to `JsonRepresentation` is not the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, you don't use the `JsonRepresentation` the right way. The method `get` of the class `ClientResource` doesn't return an element of such type. You must use it as described below:

```
ClientResource cr = new ClientResource("https://"+url);
Representation repr = cr.get();
JsonRepresentation jsonRepr = new JsonRepresentation(repr);

String value = jsonRepr.getJsonObject().get("MY_VALUE");
```

Hope it helps you,
Thierry

Comment: I'll try it and let you know.
Thanks for the answer anyway

Comment: Well, it did not work.
it fell on `org.json.JSONException: The thread blocked at the cyclic barrier has timed out.`

Comment: Turned to use **apache**'s `HttpClient`. It seems to do the job.

Comment: Can you tell me the version of Restlet you use? In addition can you give the JSON content you trying to parse? Thanks!

Comment: I tried your solution on a simple Restlet client-server, and it works. It seems that I have other issues in my original program. Thanks for the help.